# PHP Regex match mulitpile maches in string?

Tags: php, regex

How can I add a check in regex for specific strings (quoted) and at the same time be prioritized over the regex that contains @ (\w+)?

> @webutvikler @administrator @bugfinder & utvikler @moderator @chat- &
>   forummoderator @ideutvikler

```
<?php
$alphaUsername = array();
preg_match_all("/@(\w+)/", $input, $matches);
if (!empty($matches[1])) {
    $alphaUsername = array_map('mysql_escape', $matches[1]);
}
?>
```

I tried different solutions with | in the regex check but strings like: "@bugfinder & utvikler" only return "@bugfinder" and not the rest of the string.

Comment: Is it all in one line or are there new lines after each tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?
https://regex101.com/r/1Hd7k8/1

```
$str = '@webutvikler @administrator @bugfinder & utvikler @moderator @chat- & forummoderator @ideutvikler';

preg_match_all('/@([\w &-]+)/', $str, $matches);
```

I added \w inside a [] bracket and included space & and - to make it match any of those multiple times.

Edit; you will need to trim the strings when you output them since they will include the space at the end.
Just use `echo trim($matches[0]);` or similar.

Comment: @3kbest regex returns as expected. https://3v4l.org/2fAI6 you have a problem with your other function

Comment: I found out the problem, I had to use htmlspecialchars_decode function on the first input.

Thanks for help